# Blank page if image upload size exceed 45kb on the server IIS6

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-6

I am developing site using IIS6. i am trying to upload images on server but images more than 45 kb is not uploading. i am getting blank page after upload images more than 45kb and I heave changed in web.config also. Here is web.config info :

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" maxRequestLength="10485760">
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10485760" ></requestLimits>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

Please help. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Source** `http://helpnotes.vpasp.com/kb/611-General-hosting-questions/1051-Fixing-image-file-upload-errors-in-IIS-6-and-7/`

**For IIS 6:**

- Go to IIS and right click the server, select properties, and check
  the box "Allow changes to MetaBase configuration while IIS is
  running"; if after this step the metabase file is still locked, try
  turning off IIS or even restarting the machine in safe mode.
- Open in a text editor the Metabase file, which can be found at
  `c:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\MetaBase.xml`.
- The variable `AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed` limits the number of bytes
  in the page request (by default `200KB`); change the value to
  `1073741824` (unlimited) or to a limit of your choice. Check whether
  the same variable shows up in other places in the file and change
  them too.

**For IIS 7:**

- Highlight your website, then open the "Advanced Settings..." link in
  the right-most panel. Set "ConnectionTime-out (seconds)" to a much
  bigger number. For example: "3600", which is an hour.
- Close "Advanced Settings...".
- While still highlighting your website, click on the "ASP" tab, then
  expand "Limits Properties" and set "**Maximum Requesting Entity Body
  Limit**" to 1073741824.
- Finally, open a command window as an administrator and run the
  command `"c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config
  -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:100000000"`.
- This tells IIS the largest amount you may upload, in this case, it's 100MB. You may set   your number accordingly.